# pytest test duration with class setup

Tags: python, pytest

We have some performance test infrastructure built with python and pytest. One of our test classes must restore a database backup in the class set up, then run all of the tests. The problem is the test duration, we want to be able to track the duration of each test method over time. However, the duration of the database restore in the class set up is included in the duration of the first test that runs.

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    TestHelper.restore_database_backup(...)

def test_carbon_udp(self):
    ...
```

This is the results we see in Jenkins:

[image: Jenkins test results]

The test itself takes about 13 mins, whereas the db restore is about 40 mins. I don't care how long the restore takes, I'm just concerned about the test duration. Is there any way to run the tests in this way, where the setUpClass method duration is not included in the duration of the first test? Thanks.